# How to parallelize for loop with multiple functions inside - Python - AWS Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

Here is my question.

I have created several functions, and those functions will be **run per each UserID** (that is the reason of the for loop below running the functions). It will be run in AWS Glue.

I need to do **scalable** this code in Python / AWS Glue, working with millions of UsersID. Since each UserID has 3000 records, then 1 million Users will be 3000000000 records in total.

I thought about **parallelize** the *for loop* below, and I read about Dask, Pandarell, and some others. (Even increasing resources in AWS Glue, like worker types, but not working)

**The problem** is, I do not know how to implement those libraries when I have to run a *for loop* with several functions inside, and when the output of every functions is the input of the following function.

Does anyone have a clue of how can I parallelize that loop? (Could be using Python, Spark, PySpark, etc)

Thanks in advance

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv('C:{path}/tracking.csv') 
raw_data["Time"]=pd.to_datetime(raw_data.Time)
raw_data=raw_data.sort_values(['UserId', 'Time'], ascending=[True, True])

listIdUser = raw_data['UserId'].unique().tolist() 
poi = pd.DataFrame(columns=['PointsId', 'TimeInitial', 'TimeEnding', 'Lat', 'Lon', 'TotalTime', 'UserId'])

for i in listIdUser:
    source_data = raw_data[raw_data["UserId"] == i]
    source_data=source_data.reset_index().drop(["index"], axis=1)
    clean_data = single_outlier_detection(source_data)
    pairwise_distance = pairwise_distance_calculation(clean_data)
    data = consecutive_points(clean_data)
    dbscan_data=coordinates_data_preparation(data)
    distances = distances_estimation(dbscan_data)
    threshold=dbscan_epsilon_estimation(distances,pairwise_distance)
    cluster_df = dbscan_model_run(threshold, dbscan_data)
    points_stay = places_of_interest(cluster_df)
    poi=pd.concat([poi, points_stay])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your logic is already defined for one listIdUser, all you have to do is wrap this logic with [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue/). We can separate the partitioning and execution. I don't have data to test on but it will look like this.

```py
raw_data = pd.read_csv('C:{path}/tracking.csv') 
raw_data["Time"]=pd.to_datetime(raw_data.Time)

def logic_one_id(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # notice I remove the step to subset raw data
    source_data=df.reset_index().drop(["index"], axis=1)
    clean_data = single_outlier_detection(source_data)
    pairwise_distance = pairwise_distance_calculation(clean_data)
    data = consecutive_points(clean_data)
    dbscan_data=coordinates_data_preparation(data)
    distances = distances_estimation(dbscan_data)
    threshold=dbscan_epsilon_estimation(distances,pairwise_distance)
    cluster_df = dbscan_model_run(threshold, dbscan_data)
    points_stay = places_of_interest(cluster_df)
    # notice I remove the concat. Fugue will handle
    return points_stay
```

and then you can do:

```py
output_schema="PointsId:int,TimeInitial:datetime,TimeEnding:datetime,Lat:float,Lon:float,TotalTime:float,UserId:int"

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

from fugue import transform
transform(df, logic_one_id, schema=output_schema, partition={"by":"UserId", "presort":"Time"}, engine=spark)
```

A couple of things to notice:

1. Schema is a requirement for Spark so I guessed your output schema
2. The `transform()` function will handle the partition by UserID so you don't need to do it yourself
3. We presorted the data by time also during partitioning
4. We passed in `spark` as the engine. If `engine=None`, it will run on Pandas so you can test locally pretty easily.

You can test on Pandas like this:

```
test_df = raw_data[raw_data["UserId"] == one_id_here]
transform(test_df, logic_one_id, schema=output_schema, partition={"by":"UserId", "presort":"Time"})
```

and if it works, run all the data on the spark engine

Comment: Hi Kevin first of all, thanks for the answer and time., I got a message error, I posted below!

Comment: Hi Wal, you shouldn't make a new answer to continue the thread haha. I suggest you join the Fugue Slack seen in the Github repo and I can debug more there. This code is nearly working.